# How to use windows authentication (active directory authentication) with a distributed setup

Tags: silverlight, wcf, web-services, security, silverlight-4.0

I want my silverlight application to use windows authentication so the user does not have to log in and I can use that to identify them.

One issue has come up though.

I have a set of super secret web services that do not have access to authenticate the user.  What can I do to make sure that calls coming from the silverlight application are actually allowed?  Do I need a certificate or something?

Comment: Define "Super Secret."  Do you mean that they are running w/o your IS department's knowledge, or that they handle sensitive data?

Comment: Just that I don't want people to access it who are not allowed to.  I only want our silverlight application to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  A client certificate is probably what you need.

Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649203.aspx

And then keep close control of the certificate.  Your web service and your Silverlight app should be the only things with access to the certificate.

Comment: Does the client have to install the certificate on every machine that uses my Silverlight app?